# Me sale estos errores en mi java netbeans 17, no me deja importar librerias e indica "Unused import", además no me deja definir variables

Tags: javascript, java, netbeans, apache-netbeans

Me sale estos errores en mi java netbeans 17, no me deja importar librerias e indica "Unused import", además no me deja definir variables.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No tienes ningún error, solo te informa que has declarado librerías y variables que no se utilizan y es la verdad porque tu programa está vacío.